# The specified setting for the option FEFloatIterator cannot be used

Tags: warning-messages, monitoring

I am currently trying to get a numerical simulation running where one variable is iterated over many orders of magnitude. As the calculation takes pretty long, I would like to display a `ProgressIndicator` for the evaluation, preferreably for the logarithm of the above variable. Trying this, I encountered the following error:

> The specified setting for the option FEFloatIterator cannot be used.

Playing around a bit, I found this minimal example that reproduces the error

```
Monitor[
  For[x = 1, x < 10, ++x, Pause[1]],
  ProgressIndicator[Log[x], {Log[1], Log[10]}]
]
```

The option `FEFloatIterator` seems to be undocumented, so I don't know what to do with this error message. The problem seems to originate from the logarithms, but further then that I have no idea.

Comment: This seems like a borderline bug to me.  You might report it to WRI.

Comment: I just got the same error for a Slider where I had the range as {-Pi, Pi}. This was solved by writing N[{-Pi, Pi}]. Version 10.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems ProgressIndicator can't interpret irrational numbers (I guess because they can be evaluated with any accuracy, while indicator needs some precise number). So just use floats explicitly:

```
Monitor[
  For[x = 1., x < 10, ++x, Pause[.1]], 
  ProgressIndicator[Log[x], {Log[1], Log[10.]}]]
```

or

```
Monitor[
  For[x = 1, x < 10, ++x, Pause[.1]], 
  ProgressIndicator[Log[N@x], {Log[1], Log[N@10]}]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this perfectly fixed my problem.