# Animator not always working under 10.0/1

Tags: version-10

I am running Mathematica 10 under Windows 7 (32 bit).

One of my old examples did not run any more under Mathematica 10. After some digging, I found the following buggish behaviour of Animator. Please start with a fresh kernel and then evaluate:

```
In[1]:=  Animator[x, {0, 1}]
Out[1]= Animator[x,{0,1}]

In[2]:= Animator[Dynamic[x], {0,1}]
(* works *)

In[3]:= Animator[x, {0,1}]
(* now works! *)

In[4]:= Animator[x, {0,Pi}]
(* Mma 10.0 not running, message: "The specified setting for the option FEFloatIterator cannot be used". *)
```

It seems that in Mathematica 10.0 the command `Animator[x, {0, z}]` only runs when `z` is an explicit real or integer, but not when `z` contains a numerical symbol such as `Pi` or `E`. In Mathematica 10.1 this seems to be repaired.

But in both versions, the command `Animator[x, {0,1}]` only runs when first `Animator[Dynamic[x], {0,1}]` is executed.

Comment: I think there was such an error, I saw it on one or 2 of my demos. But now it is gone, at least I tried your code in 10.1 and it works with no problem on my windows 7. But the error message you show, I've seen before and even reported it. I had no idea why it came from. Code used to work ok before 10, and then on some demos I saw the above message.

Comment: I've seen it too.   Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66542/the-specified-setting-for-the-option-fefloatiterator-cannot-be-used